# How to Center an image on top of another image using CSS?

Tags: css

I wish to achieve the following effect, regardless browser (re)size:
[image: video cavas example]

The images are set to be flexible, so, each of them as a max-width declared as:
100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/rgdrqbg4/

The css:

```
img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.home-video {
    position: relative;
    width: 57.291666666667%;
}

.video-placeholder {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}

.play-video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 32.545454545455%;
    top: 22.508038585209%;
}
```

Can someone please point some directions, or name some common used techniques to overlay two images while keep them absolute centered, regardless the viewport width?

Comment: I don't need a specific solution for this specific problem. Just some references that I could start on, and deal with this. Thank you.

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique is to set `top` and `left` to `50%` and set `margin-top` and `margin-left` negative half of the `height` and `width` of your image.

Try this:

```
.play-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -90px;
    margin-left: -97px;
}
```

Working JSFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rgdrqbg4/1/

**UPDATE**

You can also set `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` to `0` and set `margin` to `auto` for it to auto calculate the margin needed to center the image.

```
.play-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Working JSFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rgdrqbg4/5/

This will only work if the image inside is smaller than the image that is wrapping it.

**UPDATE**

You are setting `width` for `.home-video`. At some point in the viewport, the container has more width than the image so the black box is centering accoring to the container, not to the parent image. To make the `.home-video` container have the same `width` as its larger image you can use this:

I added a `width` of `30%` to the black box so it can shrink with the larger image too.

```
.home-video{
    display: inline-block;
}
.play-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And remove the `width` you set before.

Working JSFiddle sample: Working JSFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rgdrqbg4/9/

Comment: I don't have fixed width for images. And the width and height will change according to browser resize, so I believe your technique will not work.

Comment: @MEM See the last answer update and tell me if that was helpful or you need the 57% width in the container so I can fix it using that value too.

Comment: Hm... How did you arrive to the `30%`? Have you used context/target formula?

Comment: Thank you so much for being around. I'm still not sure how did your found the 30%, and why display:inline-block?.  But I will work with this a little, to make sure a context/target formula can apply, and I can have the right percentage here. Thanks again.

Comment: @MEM the `30%` was just an aproximate good fit to the `.play-video` I gave, you can change it using your desirable percentage that represents the best proportion you want. The `display: inline-block` in this case helps the container have the same with than its content. When you made the container widther it didnt get its content's width, it had more width and thats why it failed.

Comment: Hm... I added `float: left`, instead of `display:inline-block;` and that seems to work as well.

Comment: @MEM `float: left` will make the container `div` have `width` set to its content so it will seem to work fine. However if you have more `inline` elements surrounding it you may experience some unexpected behaviours if you don't clear the floating elements. I recommend you use the `clearfix` known for this cases.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. Indeed. After thinking a little I realize the float effect there. I often avoid extra semantic things like clearfix method, and I'm doing fine so far. 90% of the cases, I contain floats using, mainly, `overflow: hidden;`, with a declared width on the floated elements. Cheers.

Comment: @MEM thats Ok, the `overflow: hidden` clears the floating elements as well, the only case you won't want to use it is when you have absolute positioned elements inside that element that you give `top`, `left,`, `bottom`, or `right` negative properties so they flow out of your container and you still want to make them visible, in that case `clearfix` is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.home-video {
    position: relative;
    width: 57.291666666667%;
}

.video-placeholder {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}

.play-video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 32.545454545455%;
    top: 25.508038585209%;
    width: 34%;
    height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-video">
    <img class="video-placeholder" src="http://lorempixel.com/570/320/" alt="video"/>
    <img class="play-video" src="http://lorempixel.com/194/180/cat/" alt="play this video"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP wants to center the image with a centering technique, not to find and aproximate percentage of `top` and `left` for it to seem centered.

Comment: That seems to do the intended result. Thank you. But I have one doubt: How have you arrived to the 34% and 40% ?

Comment: image centered top|bottom - left-right => parent position

Comment: This is getting close but when you look at the solution in Full Page mode, you see that the central image centers with respect to the parent container and not the image.  This problem is a bit trickier than it appears!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? You were on the right track.

`.play-video {
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    height:inherit;
    left:28%;
    width:40%;
    margin:0 auto;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/rgdrqbg4/7/

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not absolute centered. It seems centered, but it isn't.

Comment: @MEM see my last answer update and tell me if it works for you.